# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named aws_cdk

Tags: python, aws-cdk, python-venv

When I run `cdk deploy`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from aws_cdk import core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aws_cdk'
```

I installed cdk with npm

```
npm install -g aws-cdk
```

I activated the virtual env by

```
source .env/bin/activate
```

I'm using python3.8. I installed aws_cdk dependencies by

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When editing the python files, I am able to import aws_cdk and run individual functions successfully. I think the problem is that `cdk` is located in the `/usr` directory:

```
> which cdk
/usr/local/bin/cdk
```

And I think it's using python from my `/usr/bin` instead of virtual env. How do I make cdk use python in my virtual environment?

EDIT:

requirements.txt

```
-e .
```

Comment: Can you please share your requirements.txt file?

Comment: Thanks for adding the requirements.txt. I setup a python project from scratch with CDK 1.55.0. Executed also the steps you mentioned (as they are also shown when creating a new python project with the cdk) and was able to run `cdk synth` and `cdk deploy` without any issue. My  python version is 3.8.2 and  the cdk is available under `/usr/local/bin/cdk`
Can you try to activate the virtual environment, do a `cdk synth` and then do a `which python`?

Comment: @StefanFreitag which python points to `<cdk project dir>/.env/bin/python`. I think something went wrong with the `npm` installation. If I use `/usr/bin/python`, everything works fine, but when it points to my `.env/bin/python`, I get that error.

Comment: The `.env/bin/python` is the one that is working for me and with the `/usr/bin/python` I get the error about the missing module. If it is the other way around for you I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Faced the same issue. Doing an `rm -rf` on existing `venv` and then re-creating it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 16):

> TLDR;  `.env/bin/pip3.8 install -r requirements.txt` solved this same issue at my end

Once you run `source .env/bin/activate` it actually looks for python libraries on `.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages` (at least for me!). Thus running `cdk ls` which calls app.py will looks for aws_cdk in venv site package, not from system site-package as long as "include-system-site-packages = false" under .env/pyvenv.cfg

Comment: In my case what worked was: sudo .venv/bin/pip3.8 install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 12):

I think you have to order

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This will install the standard dependencies for your CDK project.

Comment: This works for me. But used python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt. And there is also mention about that in aws documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-python.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to re-install the `aws_cdk` in virutal Env. I hope its works

Comment: I got the same error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aws_cdk'`

Comment: Does your current directory contain a file called aws_cdk.py?

Comment: I don't have that file in my directory.

Answer (score 3):

install via cmd as below.

```
pip install aws-cdk.core
```

or

add following line in requirements.txt file

```
aws-cdk.core
```

it should resolved

Answer (score 1):

Came here with the same issue, but as Geremy hints at another reason.  On mac, when brew updates the python version it basically breaks your existing virtual environments.  The python version that CDK picks isn't the one you necessarily built the virtual environment with.

inserted this into my app.py to get to the bottom of this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

helped tshoot.

Answer (score 1):

For CDK v2, the core modules is integrated inside aws_cdk and you do not have to import aws_cdk.core. You may remove it or replace 'aws_cdk.core' with just 'aws_cdk'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I moved my directory structure around.  I was able to fix it by editing .venv/bin/activate and updating the value of the VIRTUAL_ENV env var.

Answer (score 0):

python -m pip install aws-cdk-lib

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a similar problem which was fixed when I re-ran `npm install`.  I see that you did that, however maybe running it again might help now, as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using VSCode, Then here's a quick and easy fix that I think would be helpful for your issue.

Click on the name **(aws_cdk)** in VSCode
press

> Ctrl+Shift+P

select the option

> python: `Select Interpreter`

and then click on the `Global Version`

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

`pip install -r requirements.txt -t .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/`

Answer (score -1):

You should run it in virtual environment.

```
source .env/bin/activate
```

then

```
cdk deploy
```